# How to install a command line application for Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, command-line

I have an issue regarding installation of a command line application to mac. So the issue is that i have an application (or rather a function), written in c++ that I want to run from the command line. I want to run the application as

```
myapp <input>
```

and it is supposed to give a printout (which it does). This is supposed to work, independent of my current directory. Since, as far as I know, it is recommended to use a bundle, or a dmg for more complicated applications and the application I have now is compiled to a single .exe file, I will keep things simple. How to install a compiled command line application on my Mac? So to say, where am I supposed to place the file? I suppose this is a fairly basic questions, but all questions about "how to install command line tools for xcode?" makes it hard to find an answer.

Comment: And, please, who downvotes, with out giving a comment? Not that rep is that important, but I would really like an answer to this problem. Further, I am not that used to work with Mac and I would not say that knowing the architecture of Mac is obvious.

Comment: Maybe I should add some information to make the issue clearer. I guess that it is possible to add the file in /bin, but I am not completely sure. Further I am not sure that this is what I am supposed to do. Even if it is, would /bin or /sbin be the right location then? However, these disks may be linked in some other directory. Should I place them there instead then and where is this directory? Maybe it is better to create an installation file so that I can do a `make install` (with a silent and uninstall here), even if it is only a single file?In that case how do I write the install routines?

Comment: Do you want to distribute this or is it for personal use? I keep my personal project's executables in "$HOME/bin" and add that to $PATH, but that's not a good method for public distribution. In any case, stay away from /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, and /usr/sbin — those are for the system.

Comment: (...continued) People who use command line applications are usually fine with the "Unix standard" `./configure && make && make install`, but want the installation path configurable.

Comment: @molbdnilo this is for personal use. I use it to to calculate some things for another application that I works on. I gives one bits and it returns it in hex. But do I not need to write an installation script to for make install? Which contains the path? Also, do you know a good way to learn about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line applications are searched for in the locations in the environment variable "PATH", like on other Unixes.
They don't really need "installation" of a more advanced kind than "stick it somewhere along the $PATH".

(You can try `echo $PATH` in your terminal to see its contents; it's a colon-separated list of directory paths.)

I keep a directory called "bin" in my home directory where I put my personal projects (it's considered bad practice to add applications somewhere along the system's path, except possibly in /usr/local/bin).

Then, in `~/.bash_profile`, I add

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and I "install" like this:

```
cp my_exe $HOME/bin
```

(There is an overwhelming amount of information about Unix on the internet, and a lot of it applies to a Mac.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I was really looking for something unix like, but I was not sure about how that well that applied to mac. Further, I do have extremely limited experience in installing software. Thanks, I keep this open for a while to give you better credit for it.