# How to make C++ program a Terminal program (UNIX)

Tags: c++

I wrote this simple C++ program to compare two strings for a match. Although basic, it's very useful to me as I often need to verify details multiple times a day.

I want to initiate the program with a command name e.g. `check4match` (the program name) so I can run the program in the terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void match(string, string);
int main() {
    
    string addrOne, addrTwo;
    
    cout<<"Insert str one: "; cin>>addrOne;
    cout<<"Insert str two: "; cin>>addrTwo;
    match(addrOne, addrTwo);
    
    return 0;
}

void match(string addrOne, string addrTwo){
    if(addrOne == addrTwo)
        cout<<"SAFE: strings match";
    else
        cout<<"WARNING: N0 match found";
}
```

Comment: In a terminal, go to the directory (with `cd`) where the `match` executable file is located. Then run `./match`. Or (still in the terminal) use the full path to the program (`/some/path/to/match`).

Comment: You have many options: Use PATH environment var and set it in addition to the path where your executable is placed. Create in your shell an alias which points to the file, copy your executable to a common path which is typically already in PATH like /usr/local/bin

Comment: Windows or UNIX?

Comment: Using UNIX (mac)

Comment: [c++ - How to install a command line application for Mac OS X? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777150/how-to-install-a-command-line-application-for-mac-os-x) & [c++ - How to install programs on Linux from a makefile? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654865/how-to-install-programs-on-linux-from-a-makefile)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a command line application for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777150/how-to-install-a-command-line-application-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as always relatively simple in the end. So `chmod a+x` didn't work to make the cpp program executable. Simple `make filename` (without the .cpp extension).

Then I moved the newly made .exe file to `/usr/local/bin`. I had to drag & drop the file, as moving via terminal command wasn't allowed, even with sudo.